# Is Web Audio API source.start(0) supported on Safari (it works just fine on Chrome)?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, safari, web-audio-api

I'm trying to implement Web Audio API. The code works on Chrome 29.0.1547.76 but not on Safari 6.0.5 (8536.30.1). The key is whether I use noteOn(0) or start(0).

I want to use start() so that I can play part of a sound:

```
asource.start(0, 2, 1);
```

works fine in Chrome (plays immediately, starts at the 2 s mark, plays for 1 s) but results in

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'asource.start(0, 2, 1)')
```

on Safari. Replacing that one line with

```
asource.noteOn(0);
```

works. [Well, I need to call noteOff(0) instead of stop(0).] I get the same error with start(0). So, I'm assuming that Safari does not implement start(0)? But if so, why do some of the examples at [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/#toc-context) that use start(0) work?

For reference, here's the complete web page. I've tried many different sounds/formats; all result in the same error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Web Audio API Issue</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Example working on Chrome but not Safari when using start()</p>

<button id="Load" onclick="init()" >Load</button>
<button id="Play" onclick="playSound()" disabled>Play</button>
<button id="Stop" onclick="stopSound()" disabled>Stop</button>

<script>
    var web_audio_context;
    var abuffer;
    var asource;

    function init() {
        contextClass = (window.AudioContext || 
            window.webkitAudioContext || 
            window.mozAudioContext || 
            window.msAudioContext);
        web_audio_context = new contextClass();

        var theURL = './digits.mp3';
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', theURL, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.onload = function(e) {
            finishedLoading(this.response);
        };
        xhr.send();
    }

    function finishedLoading(arrayBuffer) {
        web_audio_context.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer, function(buffer) {
            abuffer = buffer;
            document.getElementById('Load').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('Play').disabled = false;
            document.getElementById('Stop').disabled = false;
        }, function(e) {
            console.log('Error decoding file', e);
        }); 
    }

    function playSound() {
        asource = web_audio_context.createBufferSource();
        asource.buffer = abuffer;
        asource.connect(web_audio_context.destination);
        asource.start(0, 2, 1);

    }

    function stopSound() {
        asource.stop(0);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode the AudioBufferSourceNode has the state "unknow" on Safari.
In this case, i imagine that is not yes totaly implemented.

Comment: Safari 6.1 (released October 22) fixes this. The code now works in both Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 5):

In newer Web Audio API versions the method `noteOn` is renamed to `start`. Safari still uses the older version while Chrome uses a more current one.

Just try:

```
asource.start ? asource.start(0, 2, 1) : asource.noteOn(0, 2, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but on Safari 6.0.5, `asource.noteOn(0,2,1)` is equivalent to `asource.noteOn()`, i.e., it plays the entire sound from the beginning rather than starting 2 seconds in and playing for 1 s.

Comment: In order to get both safari and chrome to work on iOS I had to add this code too:    asource.stop ? asource.stop(0) : asource.noteOff(0);

Comment: @boosth That's right. I had to use *stop* too: `source.stop ? source.stop(0) : source.noteOff(0);`

Answer (score 2):

Try adding [Web Audio API monkey patch](https://github.com/cwilso/webkitAudioContext-MonkeyPatch) library by Chris Wilson to your project. 
It might help.